# "smart" label on home gadgets package and mcu

Tags: arduino, interface, protocol

Are any home gadget that is written "smart" on the packaging, capable to interact with a microcontroller through some protocol or "smart" label is just another marketing ploy?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Don't write a few lines demanding mountains of effort from others. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: And define 'smart' properly in your revised and very improved question - it's a very generic term.

Comment: definitely not every smart device ... questions like `can every xyz device perform abc123 action?` will always have a `no` for an answer ... all it takes is one to make it a no

Comment: Even I wanted to figure this one out. When does something move from Microcontroller use To ASIC or Just using a custom IC.

Comment: Very broad topic. Google and read about "communication interface", "communication protocols"

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry the inconvenience.

Comment: @Guilherme - Hi, I understand that you are trying to *improve* your questions. However you cannot make such a big change to a question, especially after it already has answers, as the change invalidates those answers. That last change (edit) has therefore been reversed (rolled back).

Comment: Ok. Please excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example:

- I have a bread making machine which is smart but has no external interface.
- I have a Sony hi-fi that is not intended to be controlled by something else but if you can get the Arduino to generate the infrared remote control codes then you could send commands to it.

Sometimes it is possible to simulate a button press on a device using a relay or transistor to short out the button. This requires a level of understanding of the circuit being controlled so that the control works and you don't damage the device.